# How to create a drag and drop GhostScript .bat file for Windows?

Tags: batch-file, drag-and-drop

I'm trying to adapt [this script](https://gist.github.com/firstdoit/6390547) into a drag and drop `.bat` file for Windows. The script itself works perfectly fine through the Command Prompt, but what I've tried has resulted in a blank output file. This is my first attempt at making a `.bat` file so any insight is appreciated!

```
@echo off
cd C:\Program Files\gs\gs9.26\bin
gswin64c.exe -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dCompatibilityLevel=1.4 -dPDFSETTINGS=/printer -dNOPAUSE -dQUIET -dBATCH -sOutputFile="%~1"_sm.pdf "%~1".pdf
pause
exit
```

EDIT: Thanks guys, I've used your suggestions to make a `.bat` that works as intended!

```
@echo off
"C:\Program Files\gs\gs9.26\bin\gswin64c.exe" -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dCompatibilityLevel=1.4 -dPDFSETTINGS=/printer -dNOPAUSE -dQUIET -dBATCH -sOutputFile="%~dp1%~n1_sm.pdf" "%~1"
pause
exit
```

Comment: What do you want to drag and drop? You need to be more specific. Are you planning on dragging files onto it or folders? if so, 1 file or many?

Comment: Not a Ghostscript question, this is pure Windows stuff.

Comment: I would want to drag 1 multi-page pdf onto it in order to downsize it.

Comment: I don't think you want `"%~1".pdf`.  I think it should just be `"%~1"`

Comment: I don't think you want `"%~1"_sm.pdf`, I think it may be better as `"%~dp1%~n1_sm.pdf"`

Answer (score -1):

```
@echo off
"C:\Program Files\gs\gs9.26\bin\gswin64c.exe" -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dCompatibilityLevel=1.4 -dPDFSETTINGS=/printer -dNOPAUSE -dQUIET -dBATCH -sOutputFile="%~dp1%~n1_sm.pdf" "%~1"
pause
exit
```

Comment: Just take account that your code only uses `%1`, which means that you should only use the script to drag and drop onto. If you decide to use it otherwise, please make sure that your input file is doublequoted if it contains any one of a few different characters. The drop method automatically includes the doublequotes if needed.